# What's the difference between RegisterSystemDirectories and other methods

Tags: .net, fonts, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm using the iText 7 .NET dll and I want to know what's the difference between the `PdfFontFactory.RegisterSystemDirectories()` methods and the following ones:

- `PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("calibri", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, True)`
- `PdfFontFactory.RegisterDirectory("C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibri")`
- `FontProgramFactory.RegisterFontDirectory("C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibri")`
- `FontProgramFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("calibri")`

Because when I ask for `PdfFontFactory.GetRegisteredFonts()`, the result is only impacted by the first one, not by the others.

I've sometimes an `OutOfMemoryException` and I saw that the `RegisterSystemDirectories` increase the memory by 500 mb whereas I only need of 12 family fonts ("arial", "calibri", "comic", "georgia", "lucida", "segoe", "times", "trebuchet", "verdana", "consola"). If I don't register them, when I add a paragraph with one of these fonts to my PdfDocument, an exception occured: "*Invalid font type*".

So I search a solution to register only these families.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have/find any answer about my question yet, but I found another method which does what I want : `PdfFontFactory.Register("C:\Windows\Fonts\CALIBRI.TTF")`. I should to do that for each font I want to use, but it saves until 400 mb of memory!